# ggplot2: Bar Plot - How to graph values which are close to 0?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I want to prevent label stacking seen here:
[Sample Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FxCB.png)

The data being graphed:

```
   allele_count allele frequency population 
          <int> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>      
 1         1865 G      0.894     gnomADg:oth
 2         4801 G      0.925     gnomADg:eas
 3          894 G      0.980     gnomADg:ami
 4         3867 G      0.801     gnomADg:sas
 5        10175 G      0.968     gnomADg:fin
 6          273 G      0.864     gnomADg:mid
 7           21 T      0.00138   gnomADg:amr
 8        13046 G      0.856     gnomADg:amr
 9         2901 G      0.836     gnomADg:asj
10            4 C      0.0000264 gnomADg:ALL
11           21 T      0.000138  gnomADg:ALL
```

The code used to generate the graph:

```
graphPREPdata2[1:11, ] %>% ggplot(aes(population, frequency)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = allele), width = .8, alpha = .5) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) + ylim(0,1) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(title = paste0('Variant ID: ', names(ancesA_graphData[77])), 
       subtitle = paste0('Ancestral Allele: ', attr(graphPREPdata2, 'Ancestral_Allele'))) +
  xlab('Population Ancestry')+ylab('Allele Frequency') + 
  geom_text(aes(label = mockLabels[1:11], angle = 35), size = 4)
```

In my current graph some values are too small to see, and thus confusing and visually unappealing in their current representation.

I want to understand how to visually represent values of arbitrarily small value.

Comment: Your smallest count `gnomADg:ALL` is 25; how do you expect to show that on a plot that scales to counts of 13046? If you render this into a fairly large file (I did a PDF, 20in square), you can see that the `:ALL` column does have a column, it is just rather _thin_, https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9NK4.png, and easily glossed-over when looking at raster-rendering and/or the plot as a whole.

Comment: You _could_ add `+ scale_y_sqrt()` (after removing `ylim(0,1)`), that way you can see a little more, at the expense of a linear y-axis.

Comment: You could use some monstrosity like `aes(y = frequency + ifelse(frequency > 0, MIN_VALUE, 0))` to make non-zero but basically zero be shown as MIN_VALUE, where you pick that value based on the minimum visible in your graphic's size. But if you're using a linear scale with a finite number of pixels then extremely small values will necessarily be visually indistinguishable from zero. You might consider a log scale or `scales::pseudo_log_trans` if you need to show multiple orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I've removed components of your plot that rely on data we don't have available.)

Remove `ylim(0,1)` and add `scale_y_sqrt()`.

```r
graphPREPdata2[1:11, ] %>% ggplot(aes(population, frequency)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = allele), width = .8, alpha = .5) + 
  theme_bw(base_size = 15) + scale_y_sqrt() +                ## CHANGE
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  # labs(title = paste0('Variant ID: ', names(ancesA_graphData[77])), 
  #      subtitle = paste0('Ancestral Allele: ', attr(graphPREPdata2, 'Ancestral_Allele'))) +
  xlab('Population Ancestry')+ylab('Allele Frequency')
  # geom_text(aes(label = mockLabels[1:11], angle = 35), size = 4)
```

[image: sqrt y-axis]

Comment: I seem to have been missing the fact multiple observations fell under the same 'population' category. (which is why I was seeking 11 bar positions not the 9 seen). I see how your answer is a potential solution for visibility and want to keep the post up for that sake, as it may serve others. Editing my initial post to remove my misunderstandings which may be misleading.